# On hover data fluctuation issue in chart.js graph react js .How can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

If i use event:[] then hover issue will fix, but i also want tooltip.

```
import Chart from "chart.js";


const Component1 = ({productData,truncatedNames}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("myChart1");
    // Create the chart context
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  
    // Define the chart data
    const data = {
      labels: truncatedNames,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Products",
          data: productData,
          backgroundColor: "#FA7070",
        },
      ],
    };

    // Configure the chart options
    const options = {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            display: true,
            ticks: {
              suggestedMin: 0,
              beginAtZero: true,
              callback: productData ? yAxisLabelCallback : emptyFunction,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      onHover: function (event, chartElements) {},
      hover: false,
    };

    // Create the bar chart
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: data,
      options: options,
    });
  }, []);
  return (
   
      <Box>
        <canvas width={"70%"} height={"40%"} id="myChart1"></canvas>
      </Box>
  
  );
};

export default Component1;
```

Please tell or give any example how I destroy my chart after displaying another customer data.
I am unable to destroy this in useEffect because if i console myChart then it gives undefined value.

Comment: Maybe you could make use of cleanup function of useEffect

Comment: @CodeThing can you customize this function in my code?

Comment: What is your requirement. Do you want the bar to refresh when new props are passed?

Comment: Yes , Currently if I change/switch customer 1 data to customer 2 , then the customer 1 data is reflecting on the graph if I hover on the bars.

Comment: That's because you are not passing dependancies (productData and truncatedNames) to the use effect when component is re-rendered after props are changed.

Comment: I've tried it , but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you update the code with what you have tried?

Comment: if I pass event:[ ] in the options obj then hover issue will fix and tooltip also don't work , but I also want to show tooltip for showing details of the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,
Your component is not refreshed with new data because you are not passing dependancies (productData and truncatedNames) to the use effect.
The dependancies will rerun the effect after props are changed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ... Other code

    // Create the bar chart
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: data,
      options: options
    });

    return () => {
      // doing cleanup 
      myChart.destroy(); 
    };
  }, [productData, truncatedNames]);
```

Also you need to add clean up function which will destroy the old chart and render new one in the useEffect.